# python SMTP - socket error

Tags: python, sockets, smtp

I have a python script to run a SMTP server in localhost. This is my very simple code:

```
import smtpd
import asyncore

class CustomSMTPServer (smtpd.SMTPServer):

    def process_message(self, peer, mailfrom, rcpttos, data):
        print 'Receiving message from:', peer
        print 'Message addressed from:', mailfrom
        print 'Message addressed to  :', rcpttos
        print 'Message length        :', len(data)

 server = CustomSMTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 25), None)

 asyncore.loop()
```

If I send an email from an email client running on localhost the email arrives successfully in the STMP server. However, if I send an email from an email client running in a computer located in the same local network (192.168.1.1/24), it doesn't succeed. Here below the error I get from Outlook Express:

```
The connection to the server has failed. Account 'localhost', Server '192.168.1.115'.        
Protocol SMTP, Port: 25, Secure(SSL): No, Socket Error: 10061, Error Number: 0x800CCC0E
```

Just in case, I deactivated McAfee firewall in both PCs but I still get the same error.

Where can be the problem? Does it have anything to do with the asyncore.loop() method? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your server is running on the loopback interface:

```
server = CustomSMTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 25), None)
```

That interface is not reachable from any external network, only from the local machine.

You will need to start your email server on a real network interface (such as 192.168.1.115, based on the error message).

Also, I doubt you'll be able to retrieve any message anyway. You are running an SMTP server: it accepts messages over SMTP but will not provided POP3 / IMAP services, so you can't retrieve messages using a remote email client. The SMTP server can be used to store messages in a local file-based message store though (and en email client running on the same machine could retrieve messages from the file, if correctly formatted).